# Append parameter to page inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe, parameters, wiki, purge

I am making a tiny bot-like page that will redirect the user to a certain page plus a paramater.

Basically:

1. A page inside an iframe redirects the user to a random page on my site (already done)
2. The script appends ?action=purge to the page inside the iframe
3. The script refreshes the page after 1 second (already done)

The part I need is the middle part, I have no idea how to do that.  I know you can use the meta refresh to redirect, but how do you make it so the URL reads the iframe's URL plus `?action=purge"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var src1 = document.getElementById('id_of_the_iframe').getAttribute('src');
var src2 = src1 + '?action=purge';
document.getElementById('id_of_the_iframe').setAttribute('src',src2);
```

If this doesn't work or is not what you are looking for then I don't know.

**Edit:**

Make sure you call the script after the page has loaded, since you can't change what hasn't been loaded into the DOM in a page yet.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm not sure, but it might work for you since you did want to CHANGE it.

Comment: It seems the website won't let it be open in an iframe, any way we could change it to a new window?